# Make the text of a disabled textbox easier to see

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a text box that when it is disabled the text in it is gray and kind of dithered.  (This is the standard functionality.)

Is there a way to make this easier to see?

I have tried this:

```
txtBoxNumber.Enabled = false;
txtBoxNumber.ForeColor = Color.Black;
```

and that has no effect.

NOTE: This is a .net Compact Framework app, but I am not tagging the question with CF because I think it is the same for normal .net.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why don't you make the [TextBox.ReadOnly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx) instead? That would allow the user to see & copy the textbox value, but not change it. A read-only textbox is usually rendered the same way as a normal textbox.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.readonly.aspx):

> You can use this feature instead of disabling the control with the Enabled property to allow the contents to be copied and ToolTips to be shown.

Answer (score 10):

```
txtBoxNumber.ReadOnly = true;
// Then set your styles here...
```

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

I often set it to read only or if you have to use disabled set the text box color to white and the font color to black.

Answer (score 0):

Just make the text box Read-Only. And then if you need to set style, set it.